# HDD Surface Read test showing very slow blocks (> 500 ms). How can I fix?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I am performing a hdd read surface test with hddscan and it is showing some very slow sectors. Is this ok? Can I fix this somehow?[image]

Comment: Only 2.5147869472498289944875870116284e-4% of your blocks are around 500 ms access time.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Your slowest blocks add to around to 307 block * 512kB block size= 157,184 kB which is around 1/10 of 1 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing to worry about. Sometimes slow reads are due to small shocks or vibrations to the chassis of the drive, and not something wrong with drive itself.

If you run the test again, I bet you'll get a completely different number of blocks that are slow.

And, as the commenters above me said, the amount of space that is slow is extremely small.

Comment: Okay. What if I have hundreds of slow blocks with read time 2-4 sec?